# Reading file/calling script doesn't have the same result in preg_match_all that have the text in the code

Tags: php, regex, linux

I have one PHP script that have to search the information in one result shell script, this shell script make one connection ssh, get the route table and save this in one .txt file, but if i try to read the file or get the information direct from the script and make my search with preg_match_all, the result is empty, but i put the result direct in my file php, the code work fine, so i'm lost with this problem, my php code is:

```
$resultsCK = array();

//     ([0])           [1]                  [2]       [3]       [4]            [5]          [6]                                [7]                           ([8])                     

$searchTextG = "/(S|R|B|O|A|K|H|P|U|i) +(IA|E|N|) +([0-9.]+)\/([0-9]+) +via +([0-9.]+), +([a-zA-Z0-9.]+|), +cost +(?:[0-9]+:|)([0-9]+), +age +[0-9]+ +\n((?: +via +[0-9.]+, +(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+|) +\n)*)/";

$searchTextC = "/(C) +([0-9.]+)\/([0-9]+) +is directly connected, +([a-zA-Z0-9.]+) +\n/";
foreach ($ciscoCk as $ipCk) {

   shell_exec('./tmp/routeCk.sh ' . $ipCk . ' 22 commandeCk > /tmp/resultRouteCk.txt');
   $txt=  file_get_contents('/tmp/resultRouteCk.txt');

   $matches = [];
   preg_match_all($searchTextG, $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $id => $match) {
        unset($matches[$id][0]);
        if (isset($match[8])) {
            preg_match_all($searchSubTextG, $match[8], $subpatternMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
            unset($matches[$id][8]);
            foreach ($subpatternMatches as $spmid => $spm) {
                unset($subpatternMatches[$spmid][0]);
                $matches[$id][8][] = $subpatternMatches[$spmid];
            }
        }
    }
    //g of general
    $resultsCK[$ipCk]["g"] = $matches;

    $matches = [];

    preg_match_all($searchTextC, $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $id => $match) {
         unset($matches[$id][0]);
    }

    $resultsCK[$ipCk]["c"] = $matches;

}

var_dump($resultsCK);
```

So i already tryed:

```
   shell_exec('./tmp/routeCk.sh ' . $ipCk . ' 22 commandeCk > /tmp/resultRouteCk.txt');
   $txt=  file_get_contents('/tmp/resultRouteCk.txt');
```

This to :

```
   $txt=('./tmp/routeCk.sh ' . $ipCk . ' 22 commandeCk');
```

And doesnt work, but if i put

```
$txt="
Codes: C - Connected, S - Static, R - RIP, B - BGP,
       O - OSPF IntraArea (IA - InterArea, E - External, N - NSSA)
       A - Aggregate, K - Kernel Remnant, H - Hidden, P - Suppressed,
       U - Unreachable, i - Inactive

O E       0.0.0.0/0           via 10.140, bond1.30, cost 1:10, age 5  
                              via 10.141, bond1.31  
                              via 10.142, bond1.32  
O E       10.112/23       via 10.140, bond1.30, cost 46:1, age 2511  
O E       10.112/23       via 10.140, bond1.30, cost 46:1, age 2511  
O IA      10.138/29       via 10.140, bond1.30, cost 46, age 1029440  
C         10.141/29    is directly connected, bond2.35
C         10.141/29    is directly connected, bond2.35
";
```

The script will work, and this is the same information from the file, so how i can fix this? can be some charset problem?

Writing this, i test change one line form the resultRouteCk.txt and test PHP with the `$txt=('./tmp/routeCk.sh ' . $ipCk . ' 22 commandeCk');` and is working, so it seems to be one problem between the file or ouput made by linux and the string in php, but how i can fix this?

Comment: Did you check if your file is loaded? Are you sure that fields are not separated by tabs instead of spaces?

Comment: It was some special character, i use dos2unix and i fix the problem, but i working with linux for linux and the output came with dos character :/ is not very logic

Comment: In this case, no need to use dos2unix, replace all the `\n` with `\r\n` or with `\R` in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem, because it was some special character, at the end i have the code:

```
$txt= shell_exec('./routeCk.sh ' . $ipCk . ' 22 commandeCk  | dos2unix ');
```

This will put all the output in unix type, but is not logic, working with linux, have the ouptut with dos character